# Force HTTPS after login in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, ssl, model-view-controller

I need to enforce the ssl connection in one MVC 4 application after the user is logged in.
I used [RequireHttps] attribute on the Login action but the user is still able to navigate with the http protocol if he manually sets the protocol to http.
How to avoid that?
I don't want to force SSL on the whole site everytime but just on the login page and when the user logs in. After he logs out he should be redirected to the homepage with a http protocol

Comment: Why don't you want to force SSL on the entire site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, you're really better off just sending all your traffic over HTTPS instead of picking if they should use HTTPS depending if they are logged in or not.

But if you still want to, try extending `RequireHttpsAttribute`:

```
public class RequireUserHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to add this as a global filter so it can run on every request. And it also does not handle the HTTP redirection if the user is not logged in, but it should be pretty easy to add in a conditional to handle the redirection back to HTTP.

Again, you're going to spend more time implementing this than just pushing all traffic to HTTPS.

---

I have a feeling you have a login controller that looks like this:

```
public class LoginController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Login() {
        // something here
        return View();
    }

    [RequireHttps, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form) {
         // test login
         return RedirectToAction("/");
    }
}
```

Notice that the original `Login` action does not have the `RequireHttps` attribute. Try this instead:

```
[RequireHttps] // put it here to make the entire controller HTTPS
public class LoginController : Controller {

    [RequireHttps] // or here
    public ActionResult Login() {
        // something here
        return View();
    }

    [RequireHttps, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form) {
         // test login
         return RedirectToAction("/");
    }
}
```

But I would highly encourage you to use HTTPS for your entire application if you're able to. In most situations the security benefits significantly outweigh the very small performance hit.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the controller is similar, but the issue is when accessing other controllers and actions that do not have the [RequireHttps] attribute

Comment: @dot404 You're asking to make sure other actions are on HTTP?

Comment: Let's say the user is logged in and then he needs to access the products/details/id url. Even if he is logged he is able to manually remove the s from https and access the link without ssl. When not logged in this action should be accessed trough http

Comment: @dot404 Edited my answer for that